# C++: How to acces static member of templated class without template arguments

Tags: c++, class, templates, static

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Test {
public:

    // Some code...

    static int member;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::member;
}
```

This of course doesn't work, because penultimate line is missing template arguments for `Test`.
But since `member` doesn't depend on `T`, i want to make it accessible without giving template arguments.

Is there some way to do it?

Comment: Move it out of the template class

Comment: Do you mean global variable @MooingDuck?

Comment: Or into a nontemplate `TestHelper` class.

Comment: `Test<int>::member` and `Test<float>::member` are two different objects. Each **class** has its own `member`, but `Test<int>` and `Test<float>` are two different classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give `Test` a default value for the template parameter like

```
template <typename T = void>
class Test {
```

and then you would access the member like

```
std::cout << Test<>::member;
```

but you can't get rid of the `<>` enterly.

Comment: This will lead to confusion if a member function of `Test` mentions `member`, since that mention would alway have to be qualified with `Test<>::`; an ordinary mention of the name would refer to the `member` of the current instantiation.

Answer (score 8):

If you declare a static member inside a class template `Test`, then there is a separate copy of the static member for each specialization (*i.e.* concrete type produced from the `Test` template). That is, `Test<int>::member` is a different object from `Test<char>::member` and so on. That's why you need to specify which one you mean.

To ensure that there is only one copy of `member` shared between all the `Test` specializations, you can move `member` into a non-template base class:

```
struct TestBase {
    static int member;
}

template <typename T>
class Test : public TestBase {
    // ...
};

int main() {
    // do something with TestBase::member
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is not one, but many static variables named `member`. Which one would `Test::member` refer to? It doesn't make sense, so it's not allowed.

```
Test<int>::member = 42;
Test<short>::member = 13;

std::cout << Test::member << '\n';  // what should this print?
```